# VBA Excel delete chunks of non-integer cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with a lot of data and I would like to reduce it by cutting parts of it. For instance, I would like to delete the real numbers (non-integers) and keep only the integers in the first column. There are over a thousand lines and a macro is crucial. A sample can be seen below (the red contours needs to be deleted).

[image]

I have tried using IsNumeric and something like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
For Each Cell In Selection
    If Cell.Value = IsNumeric(Cell.Row) Then
     Rows(Cell.Row).ClearContents
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Use an `Advanced Filter` with a formula criteria of `int(a1)=a1`.  You may need to add a header row.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than IsNumeric, try comparing them against rounded values to eliminate non-integers.

```
Sub Macro1()
    For Each Cell In Selection
        If Cell.Value <> round(cell.value,0) Then
            Rows(Cell.Row).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```